# One RAM module works but two do not

Tags: memory, motherboard

I just bought a new DDR4 RAM module ***(G.Skill F4-2133C15S-8GIS)*** to upgrade from 8GB to 16GB. Both are exactly the same (brand, specs, etc).

I have an ***MSI H110M Pro-D*** motherboard which only has two RAM slots.

If I put whichever module in the *right* slot it works perfectly, but if I put *both* at the same time the PC tries to start but it doesn't give video signal and the keyboard doesn't respond neither so basically it doesn't work.

If I only put one module on the *left* slot it gives the same problem.

I've read that some motherboards only allow you to put the module in a certain slot when you only have one module, and I think that the *left* module has never worked for me since I only had one module, but now I'm not sure that if that should be the case or if the module should work in any slot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. The [memory](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f4-2133c15s-8gis) you indicate you're using is **single** channel. Whereas the [Motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H110M-PRO-D/Specification) you indicate you're using indicates it uses **dual** channel (memory).

The answer, if it's not obvious. Is to replace the RAM you have, with **dual** channel `RAM`. :)

Comment: But even being single channel memories shouldn't them be able to work together? having at least the 16GB combined capacity